# Postgresql conditional join based on date

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Need some help
I have two tables first with trial_lessons,second with purchases:
Cut versions of these tables are:

Trial lessons:
Student_id,subject_id, lesson_date

Purchases:
Student_id, subject_id,purchase_date

The problem is that from 01.09.2021 subject_id in purchases will be null always

So I need a join that will look at purchase date and if it is less than 01.09.2021 join by two conditions: student_id and subject_id
And if purchase date is later than only with student_id

I tried this but it didn't work how I expected

```
on  (case when first_purchase.moment < '2021-09-01'
   and first_purchase.client_id = trial_created.student_id
   and  
   first_purchase.subject = trial_created.subject_id then 1 
   when first_purchase.moment >= '2021-09-01'
   and first_purchase.client_id = trial_created.student_id then 2
   else 0 end =1)
```

Is it possible to make this with join conditions? Or need to duplicate everything for different time range?

Answer (score 0):

You can use boolean logic for this:

```
on first_purchase.client_id = trial_created.student_id and
   (first_purchase.moment >= '2021-09-01' or
    first_purchase.subject = trial_created.subject_id
   )
```

Comment: This works if I make inner join. But when I tried to use left with this condition it convert to inner join. For example I have one student, who had trial lessons in 2 subjects, but bought only one. I expect to see both rows, but in one purchase date should be null. With this condition I see only the row with subject which was purchased

Comment: @SmirnovaAnna . . . I have no idea what you mean in your comment.  Perhaps you should ask a new question with sample data and desired results.  This really does answer the question you asked here, for both inner and left joins.

Comment: @SmirnovaAnna post your data, the expected results and current results. But Gordon is correct that answers your initial question. Now you have changes the question.